# xml and xslt to create a 2 column page

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="stylesheet2.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <return>
         <ActionPlanCats>
            <Recommendations>
               <itemname>Recommendations</itemname>
               <itemId>1869</itemId>
               <question>Bicep Curl</question>
               <answer>23</answer>
               <comment />
            </Recommendations>
            <Exercises>
               <itemname>Exercises</itemname>
               <itemId>1871</itemId>
               <question>Serratus Punch</question>
               <answer>Something</answer>
               <comment />
            </Exercises>
            <RedFlags>
               <itemname>Red Flags</itemname>
               <itemId>1976</itemId>
               <question>Immunisation</question>
               <answer>three</answer>
               <comment />
            </RedFlags>
         </ActionPlanCats>
      </return>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have written a xslt like this :

```
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="//return/ActionPlanCats">
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</td>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

This works but now actionplancats can have multiple tags that comes from database. i want to create a page such that it has 2 cats (categories) side by side. if there are 3 categories that it should be 1,2 in first row and 3 row will have 1 column with full width. Can some please help me design one.

Current output:

[image]

Wanted output : (targets, red flags are categories name)

[image]

HTML CODE NEEDED LIKED THIS:

```
<html>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Recommendations</td>
  <td>Exercises</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1869<br/>Bicep Curl <br/> 23</td>
  <td>1871<br/>Serratus Punch <br/> Something</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="100%">Red Flags</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="100%">1976 <br/> Immunization <br/> three </td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't seem to mention what you are using to produce your pages.  HTML?  WordStar?  Open Office?  Word?  XSL FO?  Quill pen and parchment?

Comment: Could you post an example of the (more complex) input you want to process, along with the required output (preferably as code, not a picture) matching that input?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen: I will be attaching the xsl to the xml. So the html code will be in xsl.

Comment: @michael.hor257k. I have added the html and another image too. Could you please suggest me as to how i can take this ahead.

Comment: I don't see the difference: the previous version had Recommendations, Exercises and RedFlags and so does this one.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: So, the complex one will include more categories.. so it ll just have a added section like "Immunization", "Nutrition" and so on. each of these will have the same subitems ie. name,id,question,answer,comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping over the current child elements of **ActionPlanCats** like you do with with `<xsl:for-each select="*">` you need to only the select the child elements that will be the start of each row, like so

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 2 = 1]">
```

Each child element will actually result in two rows, a header row (showing **itemname**) and a detail row (showing the other records). You can use **xsl:apply-templates** to select the cells for each row, but you will need to use the **mode** parameter to distinguish between them.

```
     <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[1]" mode="header"/>
     </tr>
     <tr>   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[1]" mode="body"/>
     </tr>
```

Note that, if there is no following-sibling (as is the case of the third element), only the current element will be selected. Then, in the "header" row, for example, you can check whether there is a following-sibling to determine whether to add a colspan.

```
<xsl:template match="ActionPlanCats/*" mode="header">
   <td>
      <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
         <xsl:attribute name="colspan">2</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="itemname"/>
   </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//return/ActionPlanCats"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ActionPlanCats">
      <xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 2 = 1]">
         <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[1]" mode="header"/>
         </tr>
         <tr>   
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[1]" mode="body"/>
         </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ActionPlanCats/*" mode="header">
      <td>
         <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
            <xsl:attribute name="colspan">2</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="itemname"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ActionPlanCats/*" mode="body">
      <td>
         <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
            <xsl:attribute name="colspan">2</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="itemId"/><br/>
         <xsl:value-of select="question"/><br/>
         <xsl:value-of select="answer"/> <br/>
         <xsl:value-of select="comment"/><br/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. This was quite complex but I realised it could be made easier by playing with the xml structure itself. This works thanks :D

Comment: I really appreciate the code. I am able to work along with it and thank u to your explanation.